# Why IIS Rewrite - Redirect is not working?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Unable to get URL rewrite to work.

http://my.domain/sso/my_app => http://my.domain:81/my_app

It doesn't have to be complicated, right ?

http://my.domain:81/my_app displays the expected page.

Here is the rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <globalRules>
        <rule name = "Laravel secure on port 81" enabled = "false" patternSyntax = "ECMAScript" stopProcessing = "true">
            <match url = "sso /(.*)" />
            <action type = "Redirect" url = "http://localhost:81/{R:1}" appendQueryString = "true" />
        </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

I am testing on the IIS server itself http://localhost/sso/mon_app : no redirect, connection failed.

I tried with Application Request Routing by activating the proxy, by checking or not "Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests".
By checking, it creates a redirect rule that I adapted :

```
<rule name = "ARR_server_proxy" enabled = "true" patternSyntax = "ECMAScript" stopProcessing = "true">
    <match url = "* sso / *" />
    <action type = "Rewrite" url = "http://localhost:81/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Nothing to do, it does not work.

No log in Failed Request.

I have no more idea.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, you help me to find the error : it's the port number.

I didn't know that the port 81 is forbidden in my office.

After some other tests with the port 8080, it's OK.

Enable proxy is checked in ARR.

Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests isn't checked in ARR.

The rule stays in the server level with the port 8080

```
<rule name="Laravel secure on port 8080">
    <match url="sso/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://my.domain:8080/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the enable proxy on ARR? Reverse proxy only can work when proxy has been enabled.
[image]

I think there are some points which make the redirect failed.

- The rule `Laravel secure on port 81` should be add at site level not server level. Reverse proxy is to proxy the request sent to one site to another site, instead of proxying the request as soon as the request is sent to the server (the request has not been sent to any site).
- The rule `ARR_server_proxy` doesn't have `()` in `match url`. So `{R:1}` always null.

In summary, you juest need to remove this rule to default site(or any other site which bind to `http://mydomian`). Request can be sent to default site first. The url match the rule and ARR proxy it to `http://my.domain:81/my_app`.

If it still fail, please use [failed request tracing to troubleshoot url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).